# Dropdown menu correct?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a dopdownmenu, only with html & css.
And now i think i made a fault.. I did not much at the moment here is my Page: [Page](http://www.skeptar.bplaced.net/Schule)

The tutorials in the internet arent suitable for me :/ It would be cool if someone can write me something about the construction. Because i think it isnt correct. Thanks.

Code:

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

a{
    display: block;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}


.li_oben, .li_unten{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Homeapge</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul class="ul_oben">
                <li class="li_oben"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li class="li_oben"><a href="#">Link 2
                    <ul class="ul_unten">
                        <li class="li_unten"><a href="#">Link 2.1</a></li>
                        <li class="li_unten"><a href="#">Link 2.2</a></li>
                    </ul>    
                </a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of technique is broadly published in the internet.
A quick search landed me in a tutorial that captures precisely what you want to achieve.

[Simple CSS Drop Down Menu by James Richardson](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/website-design/using-css/simple-css-drop-down-menu)

And here is a quick [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ro2bmha3/) from the tutorial I've created.

Quick look over the CSS styling.

```
ul {list-style: none;padding: 0px;margin: 0px;}
ul li {display: block;position: relative;float: left;border:1px solid #000}
li ul {display: none;}
ul li a {display: block;background: #000;padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;text-decoration: none;
       white-space: nowrap;color: #fff;}
ul li a:hover {background: #f00;}
li:hover ul {display: block; position: absolute;}
li:hover li {float: none;}
li:hover a {background: #f00;}
li:hover li a:hover {background: #000;}
#drop-nav li ul li {border-top: 0px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Multilevel menu markup should look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a>Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a>Link 2</a></li>
    <li>
        <a>Link 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>Link 3.1</a>
            <li><a>Link 3.2</a>
            (...)
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```